# Configuration of filebeat with ELK

Tags: filebeat

I am trying to configure the Filebeat modules to get all the logs. During the configuration I am unable to get all the logs specify the useful documentation to configure the Filebeat with ELK.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried elastic.co document https://www.elastic.co for Elasticsearch,Logstash,Kibana and Filebeat 6.3.1 using docker in ubuntu I am getting only yum logs but i want to get all modules logs into elasticsearch And harvester is not starting for modules